# How to determine if user is an Administrator, even if non-elevated

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, uac

In my C# application, I need to check if the current user is a member of the Administrators group. It needs to be compatible with both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
bool IsAdministrator
{
    get
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);

        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method returns false if the application is run on Windows 7 with UAC turned on as a non-elevated Administrator. How can I determine if the user is an Administrator even if the application is run as a non-elevated Administrator?

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: Well, for one, knowing if you are an administrator allows you to know if you *can* be elevated.

Comment: @svick: I need to display certain UI elements if the user is a member of the Administrators group.

Comment: Take a look at [http://www.davidmoore.info/2011/06/20/how-to-check-if-the-current-user-is-an-administrator-even-if-uac-is-on/](http://www.davidmoore.info/2011/06/20/how-to-check-if-the-current-user-is-an-administrator-even-if-uac-is-on/)

Comment: @aboveyou00, can't you elevate yourself as another user, if you know the password?

Comment: I agree with @svick - you shouldn't need to do this. You want permissions? Try to elevate. Don't make assumptions that a user will always run as an unelevated administrator. It's an acceptable usage to run as a standard user, and elevate using a different admin account. Flow with it, and let the UAC mechanism do its job regardless of how the user works.

Comment: @svick: That's true. But if you are an administrator, you don't need to know anybody else's credentials in order to elevate, so IMO it's still useful to know.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: I'm not making the assumption that a user is always running as a non-elevated Administrator. I simply need to determine if the user is a member of the Administrators group, both elevated and non-elevated. This also includes the case where a standard user is elevated using a different Administrator account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a Win32 API `GetTokenInformation` that can be used to check the current token. If the returned token is a split token, it probably is an administrator user that is running i non elevated mode.

`GetTokenInformation` has an output parameter `tokenInformation` which takes one of three values:

- TokenElevationTypeDefault = 1
- TokenElevationTypeFull = 2
- TokenElevationTypeLimited = 3

A value of TokenElevantionTypeLimited indicates that the user is running with a split token with limited privileges. When elevated the TokenElevationTypeFull value is returned. Non-admin user has a value of TokenElevationTypeDefault.

There is a complete code example for C# at http://www.davidmoore.info/2011/06/20/how-to-check-if-the-current-user-is-an-administrator-even-if-uac-is-on/

Comment: Link is dead. Is it best to place the sample in the answer? Not sure what convention dictates here, guess it would have to do with licensing if linking a 3rd party?

Comment: @TheXenocide The sample should have been in the answer (if copyright permits). I've learnt since I wrote this that dying links are a problem.

Comment: @AndersAbel thanks for the followup; I've only participated in the answering side of the community a little here and there so it's good to know what the "best practices" are.

Answer (score 1):

For any VB.NET people (I know you're out there ...), here's a version that I concocted from various sources and is, I think, optimized to determine whether the current user (including elevated) is in a defined Administrators group, machine or domain, with or without UAC enabled. (*Lots* of credit to other posts here and elsewhere for this one!)

Firstly, it uses a static null-able Boolean to retain the Administrator status because, although the basic check is quick, the full test can take tens of seconds, so you only want to do it once - if at all if you can help it.

Secondly, it errs on the side of the basic test being incorrect/false, which is usually the case if the user is AD-administered or if the local machine has UAC enabled. So if it *can* decide a user is an Administrator, it *will*.

Thirdly, you can add or remove criteria from the *AuthorizationGroups* as you see fit but the ones included cover most situations.

Lastly, if anything goes wrong, you'll get *False*; if you want an error, you can have one, but personally I don't see the point.

```
Function IsAdministrator() As Boolean

    Static bResult As Boolean? = Nothing
    Try
        If bResult Is Nothing Then
            bResult = New WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
            If Not bResult Then
                Dim oContext As PrincipalContext = Nothing
                Try 'to get a domain context first ...
                    Domain.GetComputerDomain()
                    oContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
                Catch
                    '... if it fails, fall through to a machine context
                End Try
                If oContext Is Nothing Then oContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)
                Dim oPrincipal As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oContext, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)
                If oPrincipal IsNot Nothing Then
                    bResult = oPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups().Any(Function(p) _
                        p.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid) OrElse
                        p.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainAdminsSid) OrElse
                        p.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid) OrElse
                        p.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountEnterpriseAdminsSid))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch
        bResult = False
    End Try
    Return bResult.GetValueOrDefault(False)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I've found the below way to work well across all systems. I needed it to work on .net 2 and other solutions such as WinAPI and Management Objects failed on certain versions of Windows:

Launch a new process running the command `net localgroup administrators` and parse the output appropriately. This works with both UAC enabled and disabled and doesn't need an elevated process.

Answer (score -6):

If you are an Admin, you could temporarily disable UAC from code then re-enable it. The registry key is

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System 
Value: EnableLUA
Set to: 0 to disable, 1 to enable

So you could do something like

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\Policies\\System", true);
myKey.SetValue("EnableLUA", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Then check your principal.. It is kindof a hack, but its worth a shot.

Comment: you mean to try to disable and if it fails you're not?

Comment: Disabling a system wide security setting just to make a check is not only "kindof a hack". It's awful. Don't do this.

Comment: I know this is old but this is a horrible idea. Not to mention that you must reboot for this setting to be read again so it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: You need admin privileges in your app to do this anyways...